# Spring Boot: Cómo enviar un archivo en SMB a una petición

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller, samba

Tengo el siguiente código para descargar un archivo, aparentemente cuando intento descargar un pdf funciona corretamente, y logro obtener el archivo que busco, pero no logro descargar imágenes.

Esta es la ruta:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/documento", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void obtenerDocumento(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam Integer documentoId) throws IOException {
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", username, password);

        Documento documento = casoService.getDocumentById(documentoId);

        if (documento == null) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
            return;
        }

        SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(documento.getUbicacionArchivo(), auth);

        if (smbFile.exists()) {

            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(smbFile.getName());
            if (mimeType == null) {
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
            response.setContentType(mimeType);

            System.out.println("Tipo: " + mimeType);

            response.addHeader("X-Suggested-Filename", documento.getName());
            StreamUtils.copy(smbFile.getInputStream(),response.getOutputStream());
        }
}
```

El problema es que me devuelve el siguiente log:

```
2019-11-11 15:24:33,778 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-12) Cannot forward to error page for request [/v1/casos/documento] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.safeToSend(AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.java:458)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.write(AbstractFramedStreamSinkChannel.java:412)
at org.xnio.conduits.StreamSinkChannelWrappingConduit.write(StreamSinkChannelWrappingConduit.java:57)
at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.write(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:240)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.write(HttpServerExchange.java:2028)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:563)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:216)
at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:639)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:37)
at uy.gub.minterior.sgdd.controller.CasoController.obtenerDocumento(CasoController.java:414)
at uy.gub.minterior.sgdd.controller.CasoController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9cb9c503.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
at uy.gub.minterior.sgdd.controller.CasoController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f883cf6d.obtenerDocumento(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)...
```

Cuando intento descargar un archivo pdf la descarga se realiza correctamente. Pero no logro descargar una imagen. El pdf pesa 200kb y la imagen pesa 100kb.
Alguien tuvo el mismo problema y encontró una forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: Actualizo: Hoy estuve probando nuevamente con diferentes variantes del código y el resultado es el mismo, solo puedo enviar el PDF al cliente, pero no imágenes. Opté por convertir el archivo a un byte array, el tamaño en bytes es correcto, pero el error es el mismo, y no tengo claro qué sea. No sé si para enviar imágenes en spring boot hay que realizar otra configuración que desconozco.

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo algo como esto, espero te sirva

```
@RequestMapping(value = "document", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamSource> getDocument() throws ParseException, IOException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = ...;

    headers.setContentLength(b.size());
    InputStreamSource inputStream = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(b.toByteArray()));
    return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamSource>(inputStream, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```